# Support vectors and relative modular operator

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm studying the relative modular operator and I'm looking for o good text to do it. Until now I'm using Araki's papers but I don't know how to deal with the support of a vector, $s^M(\xi)$, which is defined to be the smallest projection keeping $\xi$ invariant.

In order to clarify some doubts, I've seen the Sunders notes which shows a interesting characterization of this projections in terms of the range and kernel of an operator, but in lemma 3.11, 2 he says it is easy to see that $s^M(\xi),s^M(\zeta) \leq s^M(\xi+\zeta)$, and I don't got it. Is there a easy proof that $s^M(\xi+\zeta)\xi=\xi$?

Futhermore, I would like to understand better the proprierties of these projections, for example, I know that $\xi$ is sepparating if and only if $s^M (\xi)=1$ and cyclic if and only if $s^{M^\prime}(\xi)=1$.

The final objective is understand better the relative modular operators which is defined by Araki using these projections. I will be glad if someone could recommend a reference to help me understand this projections and relative modular theory.

Thanks.